# Problema com vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Não sei onde ta errado, se eu coloco o valor 7 na `matrizA` e 7 na `matrizB` e 14 na `matrizC` que vai acumular o valor de A e B, da certo mas se eu coloco acima de 14 da erro.

> Faça um programa para ler duas matrizes do tipo vetor, sendo A com 20 elementos e B com 30 elementos.
>
> Construir uma matriz C, sendo esta a junção das duas outras matrizes. Desta forma C deverá ter a capacidade de armazenar 50 elementos. Apresentar a matriz C.

```
int matriza[8], matrizb[8], matrizc[16], indice;

for(indice = 0; indice < 8; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n digite o  valor da matriz A: ");
        scanf("%d",&matriza[indice]);
        
        matrizc[indice] = matriza[indice];
    }

for(indice = 8; indice < 16; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n digite o  valor da matriz B: ");
        scanf("%d",&matrizb[indice]);
        
        matrizc[indice] = matrizb[indice];
    }

for(indice = 0; indice < 16; indice++)        
        printf("\n Os valores das matrizes A e B sao: %d \n", matrizc[indice]);
```

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o problema está mais no entendimento do problema do que na programação. Não vi erro algum do programa mas sim no que se pretende fazer. De qualquer forma, você escolheu uma das linguagens mais difíceis para aprender? Eu acho ótimo como a pessoa começa por C, significa que ela vai aprender o básico, vai saber o que poucos sabem. Mas se não tiver um talento natural pra coisa vai acabar desistindo por ter problemas demais para resolver na mão.

Eu já falei antes e vou dizer de novo que programação é detalhe. Se não quiser se preocupar com eles, realmente programar ficará difícil. Vetor é fácil. Parece que está se enrolando em outras coisas.

A descrição do problema não parece fazer sentido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MaxA 2
#define MaxB 3

int main(void) {
    int matriza[MaxA], matrizb[MaxB], matrizc[MaxA + MaxB], indice;
    for (indice = 0; indice < MaxA; indice++) {
        printf("\n digite o valor da matriz A: ");
        scanf("%d", &matriza[indice]);
        matrizc[indice] = matriza[indice];
    }
    for (indice = 0; indice < MaxB; indice++) {
        printf("\n digite o valor da matriz B: ");
        scanf("%d", &matrizb[indice]);
        matrizc[indice + MaxA] = matrizb[indice];
    }
    for (indice = 0; indice < MaxA + MaxB; indice++) printf("\n Os valores das matrizes A e B sao: %d \n", matrizc[indice]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Xe2hJH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nxyiiznx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ConcatArray.c).

Criei `#define` porque os números serão usadas algumas vezes, desta forma fica mais fácil mudar. Por exemplo, eu fiz com números baixos para não ter que ficar digitando muita coisa, mas o que o enunciado pede é outra quantidade. No seu código usa outros números. Ok, mas sabe porque está fazendo?

Tem várias maneiras de jogar os valores dos primeiros vetores para o terceiro. A maneira escolhida é inteligente. Mas tem que fazer certo. O maior erro que vi no código foi que o segundo vetor estava sendo preenchido todo errado. O código tentou preencher os elementos de 8 a 15. Mas se o vetor tem só 8 elementos de capacidade, ou seja, se eles só vão de 0 à 7, está tentando gravar onde não deve. Isto se deu porque tentou resolver outro problema do jeito errado. Resolva o laço (note que o problema não era no vetor e sim no laço) do jeito tradicional e resolva o problema do vetor de outra forma.

Então o que eu fiz foi deslocar o índice do vetor `matrizc`. Eu mudei este valor apenas. Eu usei o tamanho do `matriza` como deslocamento e deixei o índice variar normal.

Answer (score 0):

@user8470

Quando estamos tentando aprender a programar temos uma visão de que tudo o que lermos se tornará código na hora,mas isso não é verdade, boa parte dos códigos que você vera em qualquer lugar terá uma parte do tentativa e erro, tente sempre pegar o problema e quebra-lo em partes para tentar resolver, desta forma você minimiza a dificuldade e foca em uma questão por parte, fiz um exemplo de como eu elaboraria essa solução.

básicamente se o problema é bastante complexo eu ja iria pegando o meu papel e caneta para desenhar, mas vejo que este não e o caso, vamos lá.

detalhe, esse exemplo é feito em `C++`:

/*
  Faça um programa para ler duas matrizes do tipo vetor,
  sendo A com 20 elementos e B com 30 elementos.
  Construir uma matriz C, sendo esta a junção das duas outras matrizes.
  Desta forma C deverá ter a capacidade de armazenar 50 elementos. Apresentar a matriz C.
*/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
    Sabendo que são 3 matrizes e a 3 e a soma das duas primeiras
    eu ja consigo definir quanto sera cada uma.
*/

#define maxA 20
#define maxB 30


int main (){

    /*
        Declaro as matrizes com a quantidade de indices pre-determinada.
    */

    string A[maxA],B[maxB],C[maxA + maxB];

    /*
        Percorro todos os Indices da Matriz A inserindo os respectivos valores.
        Faço a Matriz C receber todos os valores da Matriz A.
    */

    for(int i = 0; i <  maxA;i++){
        cout << "Digite o  valor da matriz A: ";
        cin >> A[i];
        C[i] = A[i];
    }

    /*
        Percorro todos os Indices da Matriz B inserindo os respectivos valores.
        Faço a Matriz C receber todos os valores da Matriz B.
        Detalhe, aqui eu sei que o indice da Matriz C deve começar depois de todos
        os valores da Matriz A, faça um teste removendo o "maxA" da Matriz C, se você
        fizer isso, você estara substituindo os valores que você tinha acabado de colocar na etapa anterior.
    */

    for(int i = 0; i < maxB;i++){
        cout << "Digite o  valor da matriz B: ";
        cin >> B[i];
        C[maxA+i]  = B[i];
    }

    /*
        Aqui eu já tenho toda Matriz C montada com os valores da Matriz A e Matriz B,
        agora basta percorrer a Matriz C e mostrar os valores que ela possui.
    */

    for(int i = 0; i < maxA + maxB;i++){
        cout << "Os valores da matrix C são: " <<  C[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua resposta não esta errada pode seguir programando!!
Abaixo está o seu código eu apenas inseri algumas instruções para imprimir o índice para você poder acompanhar o numero de elementos digitados!! Sua solução
funciona muito bem tanto para matrizes com 10,20, 50 ou 1000 elementos,  a logica é a mesma! Parabéns!

```
int main(void){

int matriza[8], matrizb[8], matrizc[16], indice;

for(indice = 0; indice < 8; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n digite o  %d valor da matriz A: ",indice);
        scanf("%d",&matriza[indice]);

        matrizc[indice] = matriza[indice];
    }

for(indice = 8; indice < 16; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n digite o  %d valor da matriz B: ",indice);
        scanf("%d",&matrizb[indice]);

        matrizc[indice] = matrizb[indice];
    }

for(indice = 0; indice < 16; indice++)
        printf("\nValor %d Os valores das matrizes A e B sao: %d \n",indice ,matrizc[indice]);

    return 0;
}
```